# Scheduling a task in java

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks, timertask

In my java web application, I want to schedule a task.

I have searched the web alot and couldn't find a suitable scheduler for my case. In the application I have different types of users. For a specific user type, I want to schedule a task.

By the time a critical action is taken by a user:

- I want to send an email to that specific user and after 15 minutes
- I want to send another email and after 30 minutes
- I want to send another email and shut down the scheduler.

I know when the users take critical actions and how to send email but I don't have much experience about scheduling.

Can anyone help me for the case?

Comment: u might wanna dispatch a `Thread` whenever a _critical_ action takes place.

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you use a ScheduledExecutor?
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html

It has a method `schedule` which allows you to schedule whatever task you want (you pass a runnable). So basically, for each user you schedule a task of sending an e-mail and scheduling another task.

```
import static java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.*;

class Task implements Runnable {
   private final User user;
   private final int rep;
   private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler;

   public Task(User user, int rep, ScheduledExecutorService scheduler) {
       this.user = user;
       this.rep = rep;
       this.scheduler = scheduler;
   }

   public void run() {
       // send an e-mail to user
       if (rep > 0)
           scheduler.schedule(new Task(user, rep - 1, scheduler), 15, MINUTES);
   }
}

class Example {
    private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler =
        Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

    public void sendEmails() {
        // foreach user
        scheduler.submit(new Task(user, 3, scheduler));
    }
}
```

You might want to use a scheduled thread pool with more than one thread.

Comment: Can you help me to create same task using ManagedScheduledExecutorService ? I need to create one job which runs at 5 pm daily . it is webapplication. I searched a lot and still not able to complete

Comment: @ShwetaMishra why not use the `schedule` method with a `Trigger`? The second example here is almost exactly what you need: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/enterprise/concurrent/Trigger.html

Comment: thanks for your reply. actually its a web application and I have to use ManagedScheduledExecutorService class. the problem with ScheduledExecutorService class is ,if any exception comes it simply doenst report. but code gets crashed.

Comment: @ShwetaMishra I'm not sure how ManagedScheduledExecutorService and ScheduledExecutorService differ in terms of exception handling, but what I proposed was to use ManagedScheduledExecutorService `schedule` method. If it doesn't resolve your problem consider posting a separate question on SO.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Quartz Scheduler](http://www.mkyong.com/java/quartz-scheduler-example/) to schedule a task

Steps Required -

1) Quartz job

```
public class HelloJob implements Job {
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
    System.out.println("Hello Quartz!");    
    }
}
```

2) Creating a trigger - CronTrigger – Run every 30 seconds

```
CronTrigger trigger = new CronTrigger();
trigger.setName("dummyTriggerName");
trigger.setCronExpression("0/30 * * * * ?");
```

3) Creating a scheduler

```
Scheduler scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();
scheduler.start();
scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a tutorial on how to use Java Timers: 
http://enos.itcollege.ee/~jpoial/docs/tutorial/essential/threads/timer.html

You can create multiple Timer tasks in sequence to fufill your objective.

Example
Code Quote:

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

/**
 * Simple demo that uses java.util.Timer to schedule a task 
 * to execute once 5 seconds have passed.
 */

public class Reminder {
Timer timer;

public Reminder(int seconds) {
    timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new RemindTask(), seconds*1000);
}

class RemindTask extends TimerTask {
    public void run() {
        System.out.format("Time's up!%n");
        timer.cancel(); //Terminate the timer thread
    }
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    new Reminder(5);
    System.out.format("Task scheduled.%n");
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to take a look at the quartz scheduling API http://quartz-scheduler.org/

I have used it in several projects so far and it is really easy to setup and configure new jobs in. It supports cron based triggers or simpletriggers so you can either calculate the times for the scheduled events in your java code or you can simply pass it a cron string.

Another advantage is that its really easy to configure with spring.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [JobRunr](https://www.jobrunr.io/en/), an easy to use and [open-source Java Scheduler](https://github.com/jobrunr/jobrunr).

To schedule a Job after 15 minutes using JobRunr, you would use the following code:

```java
JobId firstEmailJobId = BackgroundJob.enqueue(() -> yourService.sendFirstEmail());

JobId secondEmailJobId = BackgroundJob.schedule(Instant.now().plus(15, minutes), () -> yourService.sendSecondEmail());
```

You can then repeat these steps for the other 2 emails. If you want to cancel sending these emails (e.g. when the user took action), you can easily delete these jobs again by means of the JobId (of course only if the job has not executed yet)

JobRunr also comes with automatic retries (e.g. your mailserver or sendgrid is down) and an embedded dashboard that allows you to follow-up on how your jobs are doing.